# Set same height for all images

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have three images and I am displaying them one by one, they have different height and that push and pull other content based on image height. When I set fixed height for image, the height will not be responsive anymore. How to set same height for these images where responsive can still work?

This is my Script:

```
var i = 0; var path = new Array();

path[0] = "/pic/Company.png";
path[1] = "/pic/S031.png";
path[2] = "/pic/AnnualReport2015_f.png";

function swapImage() {
    document.slide.src = path[i];
    if (i < path.length - 1) i++;
    else i = 0;
    setTimeout("swapImage()", 3000);
}
```

CSS but it does not solve my problem :

```
#left-img
    {
       max-height: 500px;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
   <img name="slide" src="home1.jpg" class="img-responsive" id="left-img"/>
</div>
```

Comment: And also give max-width that will display image properly with their resolution otherwise it will be stretched.

Comment: You are using css id "left-img"
.Use css class instead and use height or min-height not max-height

Answer (score 1):

Use their `class` instead of their `id`, and btw, `id` should be unique for every image

With `max-height: 300px`, only bigger gets resized down to 300px, using `height: 300px` will do the same but also up size smaller (and all will keep their aspect ratio).

```css
.img-responsive
{
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-8">
  <img name="slide" src="http://placehold.it/150x200" class="img-responsive" id="left-img-1"/>
  <img name="slide" src="http://placehold.it/150x300" class="img-responsive" id="left-img-2"/>
  <img name="slide" src="http://placehold.it/150x400" class="img-responsive" id="left-img-3"/>
  <img name="slide" src="http://placehold.it/150x500" class="img-responsive" id="left-img-4"/>
</div>
```

Comment: I am trying it, if that solve it, I will mark it as answer :)

Comment: @Smart I'm not sure what you mean, by changing your CSS as I showed and as your script doesn't do anything with the style, just swapping image src, it should just work as is.